# Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Optional' - maybe not public or not valid?

Tags: java, spring

I want to show Room Detail when I click name of room.. But I have a problem I don't know why. I using Spring MVC,Spring Boot,Spring Data and Thymeleaf

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Optional' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

I think the problem is about Optional in Service when I use Spring Data findById()
This is my code

Room Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="room")
public class Room implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID_room", nullable = false)
    private String id;


    @Column(name = "name_room", nullable = false)
    private String name;


    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String describe;

    @Column(name = "ID_status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "room_image")
    private String image;

    public Room() {
        super();
    }

    public Room(String id, String name, String describe, String status,String image) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.describe = describe;
        this.status = status;
        this.image = image;

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescribe() {
        return describe;
    }

    public void setDescribe(String describe) {
        this.describe = describe;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


}
```

Room Service

```
public interface RoomService {


Optional<Room> findOne(String id);


}
```

Room Service Implement

```
public class RoomServiceImpl implements RoomService {
@Autowired
private RoomRepository roomRepository;

@Override
public Optional<Room> findOne(String id) {

    return roomRepository.findById(id);
}

}
```

RomController

```
@GetMapping("/room/{id}/detail")
public String detail(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("room", romService.findOne(id));
    return "roomDetail";
}
```

roomDetail.html

```
<div class="col-md-7 single-top-in">
                    <div class="single-para">
                        <h4><tr th:text="${room.name}"></h4>
                        <div class="para-grid">
                            <span  class="add-to">$32.8</span>
                            <a href="#" class="hvr-shutter-in-vertical cart-to">Add to Cart</a>                 
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                         </div>
                        <h5>100 items in stock</h5>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
```

Comment: Please post code of Room class

Comment: Do not use db entities directly in the view

Comment: I edited Room Model. Please check help me

Comment: in model attribute pass   model.addAttribute("room", romService.findOne(id).get()); // add .get so that it will be directly accessible.

Answer (score 7):

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
>   **Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type
>   'java.util.Optional'** - maybe not public or not valid?

means that Spring didn't manage to interpolate the `name` property used in your template :

```
  <h4><tr th:text="${room.name}"></h4>
```

It is expected because you passed the `Optional<Room>` object to the MVC model instead of passing the `Room` object.
You have to unwrap the object contained in the `Optional` before adding it to the model.
For example :

```
romService.findOne(id).ifPresent(o -> model.addAttribute("room", o));
```

Comment: What i have to do

Comment: Unwrap the object contained in `Optional` as in my example.

Comment: I'm sorry but i still understand... what is varialbe "o"

Comment: It is the `Room` object provided as parameter in the `Optional.ifPresent()`. `o -> model.addAttribute("room", o)` is a lambda expression.  `ifPresent()` is defined as `public void ifPresent(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {`. In Java 8, functional interfaces such as `Consumer` can be replaced by a lambda expression.

Comment: Thank you so much.. It's work althought I don't understand why T.T

Comment: @datnguyen94 `Optional` is a Java 8 feature. Lambdas are another Java 8 feature that works very well with `Optional`. Don't worry, you will understand better as you would dive in Java 8.

Comment: A more readable way to unpack the `Optional` would be: `model.addAttribute("room", romService.findOne(id).orElse(null));`

Answer (score 0):

an example:

```
 if( user.isPresent() ) {
            model.addAttribute("user", user.get());
```

or

```
Long userId = ((User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getId();
        Optional<User> user = userService.findById(userId);

        if( user.isPresent() ) {
            model.addAttribute("user", user.get());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one thing I would mention, which is the native convention expected by thymeleaf for nested fields/properties

```
private FieldType fieldname;
public FieldType getFieldname(){return this.fieldname;}
public void setFieldname(FieldType ff){this.fieldname=ff;}
```

Note how field names are small case but getFieldname has the starting 'f' in caps. Similarly for the setters.

If you class has getfieldname() and not getFieldname(), you might have trouble

Answer (score 0):

In my case csv used \t instead of comma created error. Replacing or use \t separator solved issue.

Answer (score 0):

Always check for the entity's getters and setters methods. In my case I had **getpatientId** instead of *getPatient*. Since spring does theses things automatically, it expects these conventions.