# how to select a List Item by "ID" using Thymeleaf and direct to another detail page?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to build an application using SpringBoot, Hibernate and Thymeleaf.

I would like to get the "id" of a selected Service in a list of services using Thymeleaf, search this service in the database and then direct it
to another page that shows the details of the service according to the selected list item, however I am receiving the following error message:

```
 EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
```

Apparently I'm getting the "id" of the service selected in my list of services with Thymeleaf. I do not know if this is correct but at least the selected service id is appearing in the "productdetail" page URL.

View productdetail

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <h1>Product Detail</h1>

  <p>Name: </p>
  <p th:text="${service.name}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

View index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <title>Insert title here</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />      
  </head>
 <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
       <header id="home">
           <div id="serviceGalery">
              <div class="service" th:each="service : ${services}" >
                 <p th:text="${service.name}"></p>
                 <p th:text="${service.description}"></p>             
                 <p th:value="${service.id}" ></p>
                 <p th:text="${service.grade}"></p>
                 <a th:href="@{/productdetail/{id}(id = ${service.id}) }">Buy</a>
             </div>
         </div> 
       </header>  
    </div> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class ServiceController {

@Autowired
private ServiceRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {

    Iterable<Service> services = repository.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("services", services);

    return "index";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/productdetail/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String productDetail(@PathVariable("id") Long serviceId) {

    Optional<Service> service = repository.findById(serviceId);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("service", service);

    System.out.println("teste: " + serviceId);

    return "productdetail";
}
```

Model

```
package com.markus.getachef.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name="servico")
public class Service {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String grade;
private String description;

public Service() {

    public Service(String name, String grade, String description) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.description = description;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

Repository

```
package com.markus.getachef.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.markus.getachef.model.Service;

public interface ServiceRepository extends CrudRepository<Service, Long>{

}
```

Can someone show me the correct way to do this?

Comment: I posted an answer. Check this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are making a silly mistake in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/productdetail/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String productDetail(@PathVariable("id") Long serviceId) {

    Optional<Service> service = repository.findById(serviceId);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("service", service);

    System.out.println("teste: " + serviceId);

    return "productdetail";
}
```

You are defining model and view. According to your requirement your controller will be look like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/productdetail/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String productDetail(@PathVariable("id") Long serviceId, Model model) {

    Service service = repository.getFirstById(serviceId);

    model.addAttribute("service", service);

    System.out.println("teste: " + serviceId);

    return "productdetail";
}
```

Try this and give a reply whether it working or not

Comment: Avijit, I did as you showed me and the message error has changed. `EL1008E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Optional' - maybe not public or not valid?` Do you know what is the problem with my Optional variable and how can I fix it? thanks mate

Comment: It seems this guy had the same problem than me.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904742/property-or-field-name-cannot-be-found-on-object-of-type-java-util-optional] I have tried it out, but I don't know how to apply this solution to my code.

Comment: @MarkusBranco I updated my answer. Can you please try

Comment: Avijit, it shows a message error saying I can't cast from Optional<Service> to Service

Comment: @MarkusBranco Can you please post `ServiceRepository` ?

Comment: It Woooorks. Thank you very much. If you have a time could you explain me this alteration? thanks

Comment: @MarkusBranco https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ this link will help you